# Brightness control by slider not working

Tags: permissions, brightness, backlight

I accidentally used `"chmod -R 755"` command in the root directory and halfway through the command executing I force shut downed my system. Now the boot time has gotten slower and also `sudo` wouldn't work which I fixed later. My system seems to be working just fine except that the brightness control, both the function keys and the slider , is not working. **Though I can still change the brightness by directly changing the value of `sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` file.**
**So, how can I fix the brightness control? (reinstalling the whole system seems like a hassle which I don't wanna go through right now )**

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `chmod +x 755`? There's no way to revert all of the changes you made to permissions if you ran this command recursively (with the `-R` tag) as root user in your root directory and let it go for a bit.  Your system is not going to be fine: proper permissions and ownership of system files are essential for everything to run properly and to ensure your system security.

I'm sorry but the command you executed is probably going to require that you reinstall the operating system.  It's going to be much less of a hassle than trying to figure out which permissions were changed and trying to individually restore the permissions of every single file that was altered.

I recommend if you are running "risky" operations to type out your commands in a notepad first, so you don't accidentally hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on something that will destroy your system like `sudo rm -rf /`

Comment: Yes , chmod that was. Edited. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about file permissions security too much if it's a personal laptop, especially the +x bit. Directories are already +x, and files can potentially be executed without the +x, so it's not much of a security issue. We should check step by step how the brightness adjustment system works, then fix it. It would be possible to fix all the permissions by comparing to another Ubuntu install. As I recall, most folders either have executable files (e.g. /bin) or don't (e.g. /var). As for avoiding this trouble, don't use the shell as root, use sudo, and think twice before pressing enter.

Comment: I'd suggest to use a script to fix the permissions. Check the permissions on one install, and generate a script to fix permissions on the other. I'm using Debian, not Ubuntu, but I expect they would be mostly similar, so maybe I could help. It's widely recommended to use `sudo` with each command that needs root permissions, rather than running a root shell, and this does reduce the incidence of accidents like this one. I'm not sure exactly what command the OP ran, `chmod +x 755` is not a correct command. If he changed all the permissions to 755, with `chmod -R 755 /`, that's serious.

Comment: @SamWatkins I vaguely remember using -R as an argument. I actually copy pasted that command.

Comment: Just found the exact command that I used. It was "sudo chmod -R 755 /". Sorry for the previous mistakes.